# Pythonic Prime Generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I am using a sieve to return all primes under `N`:

```
def prime_gen(n):
    a = [x for x in range(2, n+1)]
    for b in range(2, round(n**.5)):
        c = 2
        while b*c <= n:
            if b*c in a:
                a.remove(b*c)
            c += 1
    return(a)
```

Is the conditional `if b*c in a` iterating through the list again? Without using a different algorithm entirely, how do I make this code more efficient and pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Python's math library

You can either import the whole math library, or just import the modules you need.

```
from math import sqrt, floor
```

### Use a dictionary instead of a list

Yes, `if b*c in a` iterates through the list. However, if you use a dictionary, it takes only a single operation to look up any value. This is because Python stores dictionary keys and values as a hash table.

You can use Python's [dict comprehension syntax](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in iterable}
```

The result looks like this:

```
from math import sqrt, floor

def prime_gen(n):
    a = {k: 0 for k in range(2, n+1)}
    for b in range(2, floor(sqrt(n))):
        c = 2
        while b*c <= n:
            if b*c in a:
                a.remove(b*c)
            c += 1
    return(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty code, but you could make it more efficient. For example, you're iterating through all the values from 2 to `sqrt(n)`. Can you iterate through only the prime ones? Take a look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes for more inspiration. Furthermore, I believe that if you stuck the `remove` statement into a `Try` block instead of an `if` statement, it would only have to search the space twice.